# How to properly assign permissions for access token with Azure AD authorization flow?

Tags: javascript, azure, next.js, azure-api-management

I am building a small nextjs app that has the following flow:

- Login a user through azure ad, using next-auth
- Using the access token from login, allow the user to trigger a SQL Database Sync using a button in the application

As of now, I can login the users just fine. However, when I go to trigger a sync, I get a 401 error code and the following message:
`Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/7fa9636e-d679-4ddb-8a64-ea9ca3b3d21b", error="invalid_token", error_description="Could not find identity for access token."`

I believe I have configured azure appropriately. I have added the following API permissions to the App Registration in the Azure Portal:

```
- Azure SQL Database (user_impersonation)
- Azure Service Management (user_impersonation)
- Microsoft Graph (email, openid, profile, User.Read)
```

I have added the following scope to the authorization parameters in the Next-auth options:

```
params: {scope: "User.Read User.Read.All offline_access .default",},
```

At the following URL, you can sign in and test this process. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/sync-groups/trigger-sync?tabs=HTTP) I can sign in just fine and make a request with the bearer token generated by that website.
A request with the same parameters through Postman works just fine if I use the azure portal generated bearer token. When I try to use the bearer token generated through my web app, I get the same 401 error.

What else could I be missing?

Comment: What are the scopes for which you are acquiring token in your app?

Comment: @GauravMantri I updated my question to include the token scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you are using an access token acquired for different scopes to perform the Azure resource manager operation.

For Azure resource manager operations, the token must be acquired for `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope. Please try by acquiring the token for correct scope and you should not get the error.

Comment: So if I understand you right, I follow the authorization flow to sign in a user, and then I have to make an additional call to acquire a different token, after the user has been signed in, for the Azure resource manager operations? Can next-auth be used to acquire a token from that endpoint, `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`?